# Time series that are correlated in levels but not first differences

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series

Is it correct to say that the two time series are correlated in levels, but not first differences?

$$x_{t}=\phi t+u_{t}\\ y_{t}=\rho t+\epsilon_{t}$$

where $\epsilon_{t}$ and $u_{t}$ are mutually orthogonal white noise processes, and $\phi$, $\rho>0$. The first differences of these time series are: $$\Delta x_{t}=\phi+\Delta u_{t}\\ \Delta y_{t}=\rho+\Delta \epsilon_{t} $$

The level series will clearly be correlated as they both have a deterministic time trend. The first differences, however, do not. Is this reasoning correct? Thank you.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: It is true for this case

Comment: Hi: In time series, one doesn't really ( atleast in my experience ) talk about correlation due to time trend because correlation is a property that should be void of deterministic effects. In other words, correlation is measured after deterministic effects ( trends, seasonality ) have been removed. Also, there's a very famous concept called "spurious regression" which might be related to your post. Google for that and see because I'm not absolutely certain.